# How to get the total profit per item sale per day

Tags: sql-server, database

I have the following datatables

```
Sales: Id, itemId, timestamp
Items: itemId, price.
```

I have many items for sale, and I want to get the sum of sales per Item per day , ordered by itemID.
I have a function for the profitperitem item.count * price. 
But I want to get the sales for full day. I know I can use the timestamp, but I have no idea how to do it. Oh and yes I want to show the profit I make per item sale per day and per month
How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

You looking for this query?

```
SELECT s.ItemId, CONVERT (DATE, timestamp), sum(price)
FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN Items i on s.ItemId = i.ItemId
GROUP BY s.ItemId, CONVERT (DATE, timestamp)
ORDER BY CONVERT (DATE, timestamp), ItemId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(date,timestamp) AS timestamp,
       itemId, 
       count (itemId)*price
FROM sales AS S left JOIN Items AS i 
ON s.itemId=i.itemId
GROUP BY  timestamp,
          itemId
ORDER BY   itemId
```